# sum even integer in a list of integer (without loop)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a task: create a function that takes a integer list as parameter and returns the sum of all even integer in an integer list, without using any kinds of loop. All addition must be done by + operator only. Below is my solution

```
def sumTest(list_Of_Integers):
    return sum(list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, list_Of_Integers)))
```

I want to ask if there is any better solution, like without using the built-in sum() of python.

Thanks

Comment: You can do `reduce` with another `lambda`, using `+`, but I think `sum` is way better than that. (But I think in Python 3, `reduce` was removed anyway?) Also, `list` should not be needed.

Comment: Slightly more pythonic (using a list comprehension): `sum([x for x in list_Of_Integers where x % 2 == 0])`

Comment: This sounds very much like a homework / coursework question. You probably should look into a recursive solution since `sum` and `reduce` also (internally) use loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above in the comments, a more pythonic way of doing this is to use a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension):

```
def sumTest(list_Of_Integers):
    return sum([x for x in list_Of_Integers where x % 2 == 0])
```

As @UloPe states, however, this sounds very much like a homework question, in which case a more recursive method may be expected (rather than using the `sum()` function):

```
def sumTest2(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return 0

    total = xs[0] if xs[0] % 2 == 0 else 0

    return total + sumTest2(xs[1:])
```

This will generate a function stack dependent on the size of the list.

If you want to generate a shallower stack, then you can do the following:

```
def sumTest3(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return 0

    midpoint = len(xs) / 2
    total    = xs[midpoint] if xs[midpoint] % 2 == 0 else 0

    return sumTest3(xs[:midpoint]) + total + sumTest3(xs[midpoint + 1:])
```

The stack depth of this version will be log(size of list)

Comment: thanks. I have been trying to do the recursive sum function for a while since I read those comment above. Your solution works well. Now I am testing with